# error: unused variable (struct)

Tags: c, gcc, struct, unused-variables

```
error: unused variable 'part2' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
```

The error occurs only for part2 even though it's been initialized as well, just in a different manner. Is it just a compiler issue ?

```
int main(void)
{
    struct complex
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    struct complex part1;
    part1.a = 2;
    part1.b = 3;

    struct complex part2 = {4, 5};

    struct complex part3 = {part3.a = 7, part3.b = 8};
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if your initialization of `part3` has undefined behavior.

Comment: "Is it just a compiler issue ?" -- Given that unused variables are perfectly standard, and you specifically requested to have your compiler issue error messages for perfectly standard code, I'd say it's not so much a compiler issue as a user issue...

Comment: `part1` is initialized, then used (by assigning values to its fields). `part2` is initialized but not used.

Comment: I get told `part2` is unused and `part1` is 'set but not used' (`[-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]`).  The `part3` initializer is peculiar.  It uses the result of the assignment of `7` to `part3.a` to initialize the `.a` member — it is **not** a designated initializer.  It is close to undefined behaviour, modifiying `.a` twice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments above, `part1` is considered "used" because you assign values to its fields (`a` and `b`) explicitly in the following lines:

```
part1.a = 2;
part1.b = 3;
```

`part2` is never used, only initialized in the line:

```
struct complex part2 = {4, 5};
```

`part3` is more interesting, and I'm surprised your compiler is not throwing an error. By doing the following:

```
struct complex part3 = {part3.a = 7, part3.b = 8};
```

you are first assigning `part3.a = 7` and `part3.b = 8`, then the results of those assignments are being used to initialize the structure (`part3.a = 7` evaluates to `7`, `part3.b = 8` evaluates to `8`). It essentially becomes the following set of statements:

```
part3.a = 7;
part3.b = 8;
struct complex part3 = {7, 8};
```

I would expect your compiler to throw an error because you are attempting to assign values to the fields of `part3` before you have instantiated it. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The part3 initialization I did is just like a designated initializer for arrays but for a struct. I got to know about it from this book that I'm learning from called, C: A Modern Approach. So I think it should be valid.

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant "The part3 initialization I did is just like a designated initializer for arrays but for a struct" -- No, it isn't. With designated initialisers, it would look like `struct complex part3 = {.a = 7, .b = 8};`.

Comment: Hey, yes. I had to check to be sure and you're right. It'll keep it in my head now, thanks.